# Método ToTable não é reconhecido

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

## Contextualização

Estou iniciando no ASP.Net CORE e, para consolidar o conhecimento, estou tentando fazer um pequeno projeto já utilizando este framework. Entretanto, estou tendo problemas para mapear minhas classes de domínio.

## Problema

Adicionei uma Class Library (.NET Standard) na minha solution para implementar minha camada de acesso aos dados (DataAccess).

Ao criar a classe de mapeamento para uma das minhas classes de domínio, a ApostaPartida, percebi que o método ToTable não estava listado na lista de métodos e propriedades do EntityTypeBuilder. Além do método ToTable, o método HasColumnName também não está sendo reconhecido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei estranho, pois já havia adicionado o package do AspNetCore 1.1.2, conforme mostra a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já utilizei o EntityFramework em um projeto em WindowsForm. Bastava eu adicionar o pacote do EntityFramework que todas as propriedades e métodos já estavam disponíveis. Digo isso não só para o método ToTable, o método HasColumnName também era habilitado, o que não está acontecendo agora.

Gostaria de saber se preciso adicionar algum outro pacote, ou se esqueci de alguma coisa básica.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instale este pacote:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

Estes métodos pertencem a ele.